# Google PHP API: "invalid response from api server"

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the Google PHP API Client v2.0 in an app I'm running on Google App Engine on localhost. When I publish my app to Google App Engine production, I haven't gotten the error, but it's intermittent so it's hard to know if I'm just getting lucky in production.

My Google API client is attempting to write a file to my Google Drive. This code has been working well for a couple of months, but it suddenly stopped working this morning. I checked the Google API status and they aren't reporting any outages. When I execute any of the API calls, I get this vague error response:

> **Fatal error**:  fopen(): Invalid response from API server.  in
>   **/Users/me/googleappengine/stuff-otherstuff-111111/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php**
>   on line **312**

The file does get created on Google Drive, so my API call is getting through, but whatever response is coming back to my script is causing a fatal crash.

For a few minutes it started working again, now it is crashing again. I can't really find any solutions to the error `Invalid response from API server` anywhere... and it is intermittent. It doesn't appear to be something to do with my code, but Google says it's not having any kind of outage.

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

```
<?php
include_once('code-base.php');
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(getSetting('APP_NAME'));
$client->setAuthConfig(json_decode(getSetting('localhost_google_client_secret'), true));
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setScopes(array(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE));

$client->setHttpClient(new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify'=>'ca-bundle.crt']));

$accesstoken = json_decode(getSetting('localhost_google_oauth_token'), true);

$client->setAccessToken($accesstoken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    print "access token is expired\n";

    $refreshtoken = getSetting('localhost_google_refresh_token');

    print "refresh token: $refreshtoken\n";

    $client->refreshToken($refreshtoken);
    $newtokenjson = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());

    print "new token: $newtokenjson\n";

    printf("before: %s\n\nafter: %s\n\n", $accessToken, $newtokenjson);
    //file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $newtokenjson);
    updateSetting('localhost_google_oauth_token', $newtokenjson);
}

print "after checking access token expired\n";

print "before drive service\n";
$driveservice = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
print "after drive service\n";

$parentfolderid = getSetting('GDRIVE_EXPORT_DUMP');
$title = "00005 test gdrive.csv";
$filetype = 'text/csv';
$contents = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($title);
$file->setDescription($title);
$file->setMimeType($filetype);

$file->setParents(array($parentfolderid));

try {

    if ($contents == null) {
        print "contents of file are null, creating empty file\n";
        $createdFile = $driveservice->files->create($file);
        print "after creating empty file\n";

    } else {
        $contentsarray = array('data' => $contents, 'mimeType' => $filetype, 'uploadType' => 'media');
        if ($options != null) {
            foreach($options as $key => $value) {
                $contentsarray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        print "file contents: ".var_export($contentsarray, true)."\n";
        $createdFile = $driveservice->files->create($file, $contentsarray);
        print "after create file with contents\n";
    }

    return $createdFile;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "EXCEPTION: An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

EDIT: My code seems to be failing consistently now with the `Invalid response from API server` message. It only fails at a point where the code communicates with Google. Those two places are when I call `refreshToken()` (which only happens rarely) and the other is when I call `create()`.

I had my friend run this exact code on his machine with the same setup (as far as we can tell... same code, same libs, same oauth token, etc.) and it works for him.

Notes: The `getSetting()` function the above code just pulls some strings from my database that I use for configuration purposes. Also, the `setHttpClient()` call is needed because this is running inside the Google App Engine which runs on PHP 5.5 which has a screwed up CA Bundle and it requires me to provide a proper one.

What could be causing it to fail for me every time but work for my friend?

Comment: you will need to post the code that is causing an error.

Comment: It isn't any particular piece of code. It happens intermittently and can happen on any line of code that makes an api call to Google. One time the error happens on the line that executes a Remote Apps Scripts call, another time it happens when I'm making a Google Drive call to fetch a list of files, another time it'll happen on a Google Drive call to create a file. But then all of those same calls will work the next 20 times I run the code.

Comment: There's not enough information about what is causing the error in the question.  I'm assuming [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) is the PHP API client you're using.  Based on the `fopen` error in the `StreamHandler` code, I suspect the error occurs with either creating or reading a file from Drive.  Please provide a minimal code sample that can reproduce this error and we'd be happy to look into it.

Comment: @Nicholas I updated the code block to add a minimum example.

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue as I do not have access to the your exact cert bundle and other included code.  Nevertheless, given that this **exact** code is successful on your peer's device, this would suggest that the issue lies either with the certificate bundle, the execution environment, operating system or maybe even a proxy.  How are these different between your two systems?

Comment: I think the issue is with your `$contentsarray`, there can be some text format or special characters which are not allowed to create a file. You can try `print_r($contentsarray)` inside your `catch block`

Answer (score -1):

Before you can answer "what is causing this error" you'd first need to answer "what is the error". Usually, transient network errors are normal and would not force the app to crash with a fatal error, even if they happened constantly (eg. in the event of an outage or in your case, some local problem).

Guzzle certainly doesn't treat errors as fatal, as it [sets its default HTTP context to ignore_errors => true](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php#L333) (and returns the response anyway). The `google-api-php-client` does not change the default behavior of `ignore_errors`, nor does `google-api-php-client-services`, nor the development server, nor the PHP SDK. The text `Invalid response from API server` does not appear anywhere in the source code for any of the aforementioned projects and isn't a documented error response from any of the APIs.

So given that, it would suggest the source of `Invalid response from API server` is somewhere within the application code itself. My guess is that there is a similar type of catch-all exception handling block in the application code as you have above which is swallowing any kind of non-success response, and bailing out with an opaque error message as a fatal.

The best answer I can give is to look for source of the error message in your code, then tell it to log the details instead of obscure them, which may reveal what the underlying problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: This answer seems a lot like "That shouldn't happen... and if it does it's no big deal." Not really that helpful.

Comment: No, my answer is that an occasional non-200 response from a cloud API is normal and should be handled gracefully. It is a big deal that the application is instead crashing because of said error, as the poster reports, but it is not the API, nor the client library, nor the SDK which is forcing the app to crash, so the logical conclusion is to look at the application code itself.

Comment: But he's not describing an occasional problem, he's describing a problem that is happening at such a high frequency that it would be a complete showstopper for any production application. The application code is included above and it shouldn't fail all, half, or even a third of the time. That failure rate is ludicrous.

Comment: The issue seems to be local, based on the description ("only happens on localhost",  "it works for my friend"). The entire application code is obviously not pasted in the question as it's an example (eg. include_once('code-base.php')). It's a case of describing problem x, but it's revealing another problem y, which if solved would probably lead to solving x. Otherwise the only other answer can be "troubleshoot your local network issues", but that doesn't answer the question "What is 'Invalid response from API server'?"

Comment: Also yes, I agree the application should not fail at all! It should handle errors and not crash, preferably logging or reporting as much error detail as possible, which would help reveal the root cause. The crux of this question is why it isn't doing that, and what is the source of this cryptic error message.

Comment: `Invalid response from API server` is not an error that exists anywhere in the application code. I ran a full project search for `Invalid response` with PHPStorm and it returned nothing and even did `fgrep -R "Invalid response" *` from the command line in the project root (just in case PHPStorm was hiding some results) and it didn't find that string either. That error message doesn't come from me